# How could I store the cookie in local storage using Node request package?

Tags: node.js, cookies

I want to mimic signing some website. I need to rerun the app when it panics , and input the captcha.  I want setup supervisor to automatically rerun it and reuse the cookies I get,but I find the Jar of request dosen't have some methods like set cookies from other servers. I can only set cookie I created like the document:

```
// `npm install --save tough-cookie` before this works
var j = request.jar()
var cookie = request.cookie('your_cookie_here')
j.setCookie(cookie, uri);
request({url: 'http://www.google.com', jar: j}, function () {
  request('http://images.google.com')
})
```

and get cookies like :

```
var j = request.jar() 
request({url: 'http://www.google.com', jar: j}, function () {
  var cookie_string = j.getCookieString(uri); // "key1=value1; key2=value2; ..."
  var cookies = j.getCookies(uri); 
  // [{key: 'key1', value: 'value1', domain: "www.google.com", ...}, ...]
})
```

How could I reuse the cookies gotten from other servers?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution on https://github.com/request/request:

To use a custom cookie store (such as a
[`FileCookieStore`](https://github.com/mitsuru/tough-cookie-filestore)
which supports saving to and restoring from JSON files), pass it as a parameter
to `request.jar()`:

```
var FileCookieStore = require('tough-cookie-filestore');
// NOTE - currently the 'cookies.json' file must already exist!
var j = request.jar(new FileCookieStore('cookies.json'));
request = request.defaults({ jar : j })
request('http://www.google.com', function() {
  request('http://images.google.com')
})
```